# CypressIO make a request then use the response to pass to another function to call another request, wrap inside a re-usable function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback, cypress, es6-modules

So the issue i have is i want to be able to call a module function, that will then call cy.request() get the response and feed this to another cy.request() in a nice way.

I want to make this code nicer:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('createUser', (user) => {
  cy.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://www.example.com/tokens',
  body: {
    email: 'admin_username',
    password: 'admin_password'
 }
}).then((resp) => {
   cy.request({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'https://www.example.com/users',
     headers: ({ Authorization: 'Bearer ' + resp.body.token }),
     body: user
  })
})
})
```

I'd like to to have the two cy.requests within their own functions, e.g getAuthToken() and createUser(), so i can wrap that in either a Cypress.Command, or just a module function and call within the test file

```
const seedUser = (userObject) => {
             getAuthToken().then((token) => {
                 return createUser(token); //where this would return the created user.
             }       
         }
```

then used like so in the test file

```
before(()=>{
    let user =  seedUser();
 //or
 let user = cy.seedUser();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cy.wrap()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap.html#Syntax) to wrap the response of your first request and then you can use it anywhere.

Custom commands:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getAuthToken', () => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://www.example.com/tokens',
        body: {
            email: 'admin_username',
            password: 'admin_password'
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        cy.wrap(response).as('getAuthTokenResponse')
    })
})


Cypress.Commands.add('createUser', (user) => {
    cy.get('@getAuthTokenResponse').then((resp) => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://www.example.com/users',
            headers: ({ Authorization: 'Bearer ' + resp.token }),
            body: user
        })
    })
})
```

In your Test file you can just add:

```
cy.getAuthToken()
cy.createUser(user)
```

Comment: How does the wrap function work ? How does the other cu command know the @getAuthToken variable , is it put in some sort of global context or something ? Secondly , could I then put those two CY.commands inside a module function called seed user , so other Devs can just call seedUser() and in turn will call the two cy commands ?

Comment: Yes you are correct you can use @getAuthToken in your test file as well, as it is available globally now. For second point do you mean you want create a third custom command that uses the other two  ?

Comment: Doesn't have to be a a custom command , I was thinking of s module function like export const seedUser = () => { cy.getAuthToken(); cy.createUser()}

Comment: Also if it's globally accessible now and that response is forever accessible how does that work if I make the request to CY.getAuthToken() again to seed other users and such ?  Will it cause cache issues ? Or is the wrap the function or the response not following that part.

Comment: So whenever the first time you call `cy.getAuthToken()` the getAuthTokenResponse will have your response body. After that if you want to call that again, it just replaces the earlier response with the new one. And if you don't call it again it will still have your response body.

Comment: The above commands are very well written and you can use them in before hoock, wich would allow you to access the alliases in the test cases as you requested. Though the code will be 


before (()=>{
    cy.getAuthToken()
    cy.get('@getAuthTokenResponse')
        .then(getAuthTokenResponse =>{
            cy.createUser(user)
        })
})

Comment: could you explain cy.wrap() for dummies please haha, i've had a look on the cypressIO site and its still not clear exactly how it works, whats difference between using cy.wrap and a promise.resolve() -- i did try and use Cypress.Promise() and resolve within the then() function, but second request ended up running in TestBody not BeforeAll()

Comment: His commands are very well written. And this is how you can use them in sequence in the before hoock or in code

before (()=>{
    cy.getAuthToken();
    cy.get('@getAuthTokenResponse')
        .then(getAuthTokenResponse =>{
            cy.createUser(user)
        });
});

Comment: will this functionality work if you're running the tests in parallel ? will there be complications / issues with scope and the variables being overwritten etc ?